# transmission-daemon troubles

Tags: storage, tutorial

I set up transmission-daemon today and got the web UI working and stuff. When I went to download a small file, it gets about half way and says that I don't have permission to download it to my selected location.

All of my permissions are set for the location I selected (using `chgrp` and `chmod`), but it didn't work, so then I figured I'd try and make it work on the default location, and that's when things got weird.

The first torrent downloaded fine. When I started the second torrent, a box popped up saying something about the connection being reset, and that I should reload the browser. I did all that, but the page wouldn't reload, as if the server was down. Since then I've been restarting `transmission-daemon` constantly, then logging in & trying to download something before I get this message.

On top of this problem is the permissions one. The folder I am looking to download the torrents to is actually the mount location of an afp drive I have mounted via `afpfs-ng`. Transmission is the only program that seems to be bothered by this.

Any help would be fantastic, I've been pulling my hair out over this one!

Comment: Where did you get transmission-daemon from? APT? GitHub? Tar ball?

Comment: are you running the daemon as root? What's in the log files?

Comment: Got it from APT. My only solution was to run it as root, which I did not want to do. Obviously it works as root, but I figure this is a temporary solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the first point (Transmission saying you don't have the permissions) you can add you user to the transmission group, and then change the owner of the folder

```
sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission YOURUSERNAME
sudo chown debian-transmission /FOLDER/NAME
```

Then change the permission flags of the folder so that your user can modify it (being it in `debian-transmission` group

```
sudo chmod 775 /FOLDER/NAME
```